# Inkscape - How to center node selection horizontally?

Tags: inkscape

As you can see on the object to the left in the picture below the horizontal lines is perfectly centered relative to each other on the horizontal axis. How can I do the same on the object to the right? I have selected the 2 nodes on the top of the object but how do I center them vertically relative to the bottom 2 nodes?

Thanks in advance.

(I am using Inkscape)

[image: Comparison of shapes. The shape on the left is a symmetric trapezoid, whereas the shape on the left is a skewed trapezoid.]

Comment: I think you want to center the nodes *horizontally*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess your actual image is more complex. Otherwise you would draw the wanted shape right from the start. But to answer the question I would turn snap to nodes ON and draw a straight line between the top nodes with the Bezier tool. Then I would align the new line and the shape. Finally I would move the top nodes to the ends of the line with the node tool. See the cartoon below:

[image]

The blue line and the original shape were aligned by applying Object > Align and Distribute > Center on vertical axis.

If the actual shape is something more complex or the top side reaches further to the left or further to the right than the bottom side, you can draw another line to the bottom and align the lines at first. Move then the original shape and its top corners.

Answer (score 10):

Here's how I would do it:

1. Enable Snap to Nodes, and Snap to Guides
2. Add nodes to the top and bottom segments
3. Use a guide to mark the centre of the bottom segment so it snaps to the middle node you added.
4. Select the top segment and move into position until it snaps. Holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> after you start clicking and dragging will constrain the move horizontally

[image]

Note: You can delete the extra nodes afterwards if you don't want them.

Comment: To get the guide-line, drag from the ruler.  (Had to work that out myself)

Comment: @Kingsley - dragging the guide from the ruler is shown in the screen capture.

Answer (score 4):

My way:

1. select both bottom nodes with the nodes tool

   [image: Selection of bottom nodes]
2. copy the X coordinate value

   [image: X value to copy]
3. select both top nodes

   [image: top nodes selection]
4. paste the X coordinate value, press enter to confirm

   [image: paste result]

Comment: I like this approach because it leaves the Y coordinate unmodified.